# Are mappers reducers involved while uploading/Inserting data to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a big confusion here.When we upload/insert/put the data in ***HADOOP HDFS*** it is known that data is stored in chunks based on the block size and replication factor . Moreover Map reduce only works when processing the data.

**I'm using MRV2 when i insert any data in one of my table i can see there is MAP REDUCE progress bar.So what is the exact picture here.in reality are there an mappers and reducers involved while insertion/uploading the data to HDFS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need for MapReduce depends on the type of Write operation.

Operations like `hdfs dfs -put` or `-copyFromLocal` do not use MapReduce when writing data from LocalFS to HDFS. Whereas `DistCp`, to perform inter/intra cluster HDFS data copying, uses Mappers. Similarly, `Sqoop` uses mappers to import data into HDFS. Hive's `LOAD` statements do not while `INSERT`'s do.

And they are Mapper only MapReduce jobs.

> I'm using MRV2 when i insert any data in one of my table

I assume, you are inserting data into a Hive table. `INSERT` statements in Hive use Mappers.

> are there an mappers and reducers involved while insertion/uploading
>   the data to HDFS?

Not always. Based on the write operation, mappers are involved.

Comment: I tried all the things .Insert ,distcp  involve mappers and reducers.Thanks for your time!! @franklinsijo

Answer (score 0):

The HDFS client writes directly to the datanodes after consulting with the namenode for block locations. No mappers or reducers are required.

Ref: [Architecture of HDFS Read and Write](https://sreejithrpillai.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/architecture-of-hdfs-write-and-read/)

Because there's a progress bar, doesn't mean it's a MapReduce process.

If every file written to HDFS was a MapReduce process, then YARN ResourceManager UI would log it all, so if you don't believe me, check there

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce is not used when you copy data from local or put data in HDFS.